# Query Eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need convert this SQL query in Eloquent Laravel

```
Select * from modulo where idmodulo not in
(select idmodulo from moduloperfil where moduloperfil.idperfil = 2)
```

the number `2` is the `$request`.

Comment: where is your `model`..?

Comment: also you could use [whereNotIn](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNotIn).

Comment: modulo is my model

Comment: hooo it's ready, this is my solution sorry

look 
 $result= \DB::table('modulo')
  ->whereNotIn('modulo.idmodulo',function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->select('moduloperfil.idmodulo')->from('moduloperfil')
         ->Where('moduloperfil.idperfil','=',$request->perfilselecionado);
            })->get()

Comment: thats not even `eloquent` and did not use `model` - it only use Laravel's Query Builder. you can read more in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before asking. thank you.

Comment: Did one of the below posts answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

```
$result = Modulo::whereNotIn('idmodulo', function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('idmodulo from moduloperfil where idperfil = 2');
    })->get();
```

Comment: please add explaination

Comment: This will select all `idmodulo` from `moduloperfil` where `idperfil' = 2 and then Modulo will find all results except the matched values. Something like  Modulo::whereNotIn('idmodulo',[1,2,3,4])->get(); Matched data will not be included.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out in the comments this is not `Eloquent`.

`Eloquent` is the active record implementation that Laravel uses.

That being said if you want to use Laravel's Fluent query builder you could do something like:

```
DB::table('modulo')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('moduloperfil')
            ->where('moduloperfil.idperfil', '2')
            ->whereRaw('modulo.idmodulo = moduloperfil.idmodulo');
    })
->get();
```

The above uses `whereExists` instead of `whereIn` but should give you the same results.

Hope this helps!